# toString() doesn't work like it used to do

Tags: javascript, string, function, tostring

I have a problem.
I have a code, for example:

```
var g = "192"; //Global defined//

function g(){

    if (g<200){

        g.toString();
        console.log(typeof(g));
        g++;
        window.setTimeout("rgb()", 3000);

    } else {

        return;
    }}
$(g);
```

I run this code, and first it will return "String". But on the second run, it returns "number". Why? In the function itself there is the g.toString() method. Why is it changing to number after one run?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `g++` converts it to number.

Comment: and `g.toString();` does nothing, since you're not assigning its result to anything.

Comment: even if I set the "toString()" under the g++, it won't work.

Comment: Did you mean to give the function the same name as the variable?  Where is the `$` function that you call at the end?

Comment: Also notice that if g is a string, g++ is converting g to a number but not increasing its value.

Answer (score 0):

#### The value and the function have the same name, `g`. And you need to save the new value:

```
var g = "192" //de Global value

function green(){
    g = g.parseInt(g); //de Make sure it's a string.
    if (g<200){
        console.log(typeof(g));
        g++;
        g = g.toString(); //de Make it a string again.
        window.setTimeout("rgb()", 3000);

    } else {

        return;
    }
}

console.log( green() );
```

1. You need to choose different names for the variable and function.
2. You need to store and change your variable contents manually.

Comment: You're not calling the `green` function.

Comment: @Barmar I literally came back from brewing coffee with just that concern in mind. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to asign the toString to your variable and have a different name for your function or variable like this:

```
var g = "192"; //Global defined//

function test() {

    if (g < 195) {

        g = g.toString();
        console.log(typeof (g));
        g++;
    } else {

        return;
    }
}
test();
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rm66/1/)

Comment: That was only a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is loosely typed and will attempt to convert strings to numbers if there is an operation forcing that string to be processed as a number.

```
var a = "12345", b = a;    // "Pure" number strings
var c = "12345eee", d = c;    // "Tainted" number strings"
console.log (a, b, c, d);
console.log (typeof a, typeof b, typeof c, typeof d);
a ++;    // Increment, which forces a cast to a number
b += 1;    // Add 1 to the end, adds '1' to the end of string
c ++;    // Increment, forces cast to a number
d += 1;    // Add 1 to the end, adds '1' to the end of string
console.log (a, b, c, d);
console.log (typeof a, typeof b, typeof c, typeof d);
```

As you can see from the output, when you increment (as in a and c), it converts to a number, then increments that number (thereby permanently casting it to a number).  However, when you add a number to the end (as in b and d), it takes a string of that number and adds it to the string.

You can see in the log that the incremented form of c's value is NaN - this is due to an error attempting to cast C to a number, due to characters.